# Stuck on save/upload featured images plugin

Tags: post-thumbnails, wp-enqueue-script

Im stuck on save/uploading Featured Images. I want to upload my featured image but it give an error: An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later. Can anyone see what is wrong? And if you need more specific code, please let me know.

Code I'm using: [Link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/easy-featured-images/?omtr=b&utm_expid=3606929-101._J2UGKNuQ6e7Of8gblmOTA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.nl%2F)

Thanks in advance!

Enqueueing Javascript:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'efi_enqueue_assets' );

function efi_enqueue_assets( $page ) {

if ( 'edit.php' != $page ) {
    return;
}

wp_enqueue_style( 'efi_styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'efi_scripts', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/scripts.js' );
wp_enqueue_media();

wp_localize_script( 'efi_scripts', 'efi_strings', array(
    'browse_images' => __( 'Browse Or Upload An Image', '$pluginname' ),
    'select_image' =>  __( 'Set featured image', '$pluginname' ),
    'ajaxurl' =>  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

}

```
// Media Uploader Framework
    (function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    /* global wp, console */

var file_frame, post_id, nonce, efi_thumbnail;

jQuery(document).on('click', '.efi-choose-image', function( event ){
post_id = $(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id').replace( 'post-', '' );
nonce = $(this).data('nonce');
efi_thumbnail = $(this).parents( '.efi-thumbnail' );

/**
* If an instance of file_frame already exists, then we can open it
* rather than creating a new instance.
*/

    if ( undefined !== file_frame ) {
        file_frame.open();
        return false;
    }

 /**
  * If we're this far, then an instance does not exist, so we need to
  * create our own.
  *
  * Here, use the wp.media library to define the settings of the Media
  * Uploader implementation by setting the title and the upload button
  * text. We're also not allowing the user to select more than one image.
  */

    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title:    efi_strings.browse_images,
        button:   {
            text: efi_strings.select_image
        },
        multiple: false
    });

/**
    * Setup an event handler for what to do when an image has been
    * selected.
    */

  file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
    var image_data = file_frame.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
  var thumbnail = image_data.sizes.thumbnail;
  var medium = image_data.sizes.medium;

  if( efi_thumbnail.hasClass( 'no-image' ) ) {
    efi_thumbnail.removeClass( 'no-image' );

    var link = efi_thumbnail.find('a.efi-choose-image');
    link.html('').clone().insertAfter(link);

    var thumbnail_image = $('<img>').attr({
      width: thumbnail.width,
      height : thumbnail.height,
      class : 'attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image',
      src : thumbnail.url,
      alt : image_data.alt
    })

    var medium_image = $('<img>').attr({
      width: medium.width,
      height : medium.height,
      class : 'attachment-medium wp-post-image',
      src : medium.url,
      alt : image_data.alt
    })

    efi_thumbnail.find('a.efi-choose-image:first').html( thumbnail_image );
    efi_thumbnail.find('a.efi-choose-image:last').html( medium_image );
    efi_thumbnail.find('a.efi-choose-image').wrapAll( "<div class='efi-images' />");

  }
  else {
      efi_thumbnail.find('.attachment-thumbnail').attr( 'src', thumbnail.url );
      efi_thumbnail.find('.attachment-medium').attr( 'src', medium.url );
  }

  $.post( efi_strings.ajaxurl, {
    _ajax_nonce: nonce,
    post_id : post_id,
    thumbnail_id : image_data.id,
    action: 'set-post-thumbnail'
  })


});

// Now display the actual file_frame
file_frame.open();

return false;
});

//Removing Featured Images
$(document).on( 'click', '.efi-remove-image', function() {
  efi_thumbnail = $(this).parents( '.efi-thumbnail' );
  nonce = $(this).data('nonce');
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var post_id = parseInt( efi_thumbnail.parents('tr:first').attr('id').replace( 'post-', '' ) );

  efi_thumbnail.addClass( 'no-image' );

  var choose_image = $('<a>').attr({
      href : url,
      'data-nonce' : nonce,
      class : 'efi-choose-image'
  }).html("<i class='dashicons dashicons-plus'></i> <br> add image</a>")

  efi_thumbnail.find('.efi-images').html(choose_image);

  $.post( efi_strings.ajaxurl, {
      _ajax_nonce: nonce,
      post_id : post_id,
      thumbnail_id : -1,
      action: 'set-post-thumbnail'
  })

  return false;
  })

  })( jQuery );
```